# Deleting the first character of all the words starting with specific letters except for the first word in Excel

Tags: string, vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I am trying to build a UDF that will look into a cell and delete the first character of all the words starting with the letters "El" **except for the first word.**

Value in cell A1 will be:

El agua, El asma, El arca, Elhambre, El aguila, Elements

In cell B1 where the UDF function will be called I want the result to be:

**El** agua, l asma, l arca, lhambre, l aguila, lements

My code is as follows:

```
    Function exceptFirst(MyString As String)
    Dim X As Long
    Dim Tempstr As String
    Tempstr = ""
    For X = 1 To Len(MyString)
        If Mid(MyString, X, 2) = "El" Then

            Tempstr = Tempstr

        Else

            Tempstr = Tempstr & Mid(MyString, X, 1)


        End If
    Next
    exceptFirst = Tempstr
    End Function
```

the code is doing the job of deleting all the "**E**"'s in the words *starting* with "EL" but it is not **excluding** the **first** **occurrence** in the **first word**.
Your help is much appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `Split` function.

Comment: isn't that just `=SUBSTITUTE(A1, ", El", ", l")`

Comment: @Slai I think your formula works only if the first phrase starts with `El`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Patrick` suggested, you may use the `Split` function to achieve the desired output...

```
Function exceptFirst(ByVal MyString As String) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim Tempstr As String
Dim str() As String

str() = Split(MyString, ", ")

Tempstr = str(0)
For i = 1 To UBound(str)
    If LCase(Left(str(i), 2)) = "el" Then
        Tempstr = Tempstr & ", " & Right(str(i), Len(str(i)) - 1)
    Else
        Tempstr = Tempstr & ", " & str(i)
    End If
Next i
exceptFirst = Tempstr
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

And another UDF, using `Split` & `Join`

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Binary 'to ensure case sensitive
Function exceptFirst(S As String) As String
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim I As Long
    Dim bFirst As Boolean

bFirst = False
V = Split(S, ", ")

For I = LBound(V) To UBound(V)
    Select Case bFirst
        Case False
            If V(I) Like "El*" Then bFirst = True
        Case True
            If V(I) Like "El*" Then V(I) = Mid(V(I), 2)
    End Select
Next I

exceptFirst = Join(V, ", ")

End Function
```

**EDIT** I have assumed that you wanted the **`El`** to be case sensitive, both in the replacements and in the detection of which is the first instance.  If that is not the case, merely change the `Option Compare` statement from `Binary` to `Text`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have managed to build up, using the sample you have given:

```
Option Explicit

Function exceptFirst(MyString As String) As String

    Dim varArr      As Variant
    Dim cnt         As Long
    Dim result      As String

    varArr = Split(MyString, ", ")

    For cnt = LBound(varArr) To UBound(varArr)
        If cnt > 0 Then
            If UCase(Left(varArr(cnt), 2)) = "EL" Then
                result = result & Right(varArr(cnt), Len(varArr(cnt)) - 1) & ", "
            Else
                result = result & varArr(cnt) & ", "
            End If
        Else
            result = varArr(0) & ", "
        End If
    Next cnt

    exceptFirst = Left(result, Len(result) - 2)

End Function

Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print exceptFirst("El agua, El asma, Elhambre, El aguila, cska, Elements")

End Sub
```

It abuses a bit the usage of `Left()` and `Right()` but the code provides pretty much what yu need. The tricky part is that it strips by `,` and on the loop it adds it back. At the end of the code, when it returns the string, it removes the last comma and the space: `exceptFirst = Left(result, Len(result) - 2)`

Answer (score 0):

And `regex`:

```
Sub RegexTest()
    Dim strInput As String, strPat As String
    Dim rX As New RegExp

    strPat = "(?:\s)(e)(?=l)"
    strInput = "El agua, Elhambre, El sol, elanore, bella"
    Debug.Print "Input: " & strInput
    Debug.Print "Expected output: El agua, lhambre, l sol, lanore, bella"

    With rX
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = strPat
    End With

    Debug.Print "Output: " & rX.Replace(strInput, " ")
End Sub
```

Which should give you

```
Input:           El agua, Elhambre, El sol, elanore, bella    
Expected output: El agua, lhambre, l sol, lanore, bella   
Output:          El agua, lhambre, l sol, lanore, bella
```

The pattern can be improved - I don't know why it captures the space before the `e`, when it's in a non-capturing group ... but in this case, the hack is to insert a space during the `replace`.